# unable to start carbon-graphite on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, amqp, graphite

I am working on Sensu and graphite. Where Sensu server sends the data in the JSON format to graphite server to draw graphs of the various metrics and parameters.

I am getting following error while trying to start carbon. I have pasted the error log and trace back here. I am not able to find the solution in the internet. I tried googling almost everything.

I have enabled AMQP to read the metrics from the rabbitMQ server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./carbon-cache.py", line 30, in <module>
    run_twistd_plugin(__file__)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/util.py", line 90, in run_twistd_plugin
    config.parseOptions(twistd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 614, in parseOptions
    usage.Options.parseOptions(self, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 266, in parseOptions
    self.subOptions.parseOptions(rest)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/usage.py", line 276, in parseOptions
    self.postOptions()
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/conf.py", line 188, in postOptions
    program_settings = read_config(program, self)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/conf.py", line 497, in read_config
    settings.readFrom(config, section)
  File "/opt/graphite/lib/carbon/conf.py", line 137, in readFrom
    value = parser.getboolean(section, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 370, in getboolean
    raise ValueError, 'Not a boolean: %s' % v
ValueError: Not a boolean: False
ENABLE_AMQP = True
AMQP_VERBOSE = True
AMQP_HOST = 192.168.1.134
AMQP_PORT = 5671
AMQP_VHOST = /sensu
AMQP_USER = sensu
AMQP_PASSWORD = mypass
AMQP_EXCHANGE = metrics
AMQP_METRIC_NAME_IN_BODY = True
```

Kindly help me out. I am in need of it....

Comment: carbon daemons do not expect JSON.

Comment: But before that I am not to able to start the carbon itself

Comment: Issue in config. It is expecting a boolean somewhere and you are passing 'False'. :/ Recheck. Or paste all of it somewhere and link. i'll take a look 10 hrs from now.

Comment: But the default settings parameter which I need to pass to start amp listener. But its allowing that

Comment: Remove the amqp settings from config and try starting carbon. This way you can localize the error-zone.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of those coming from Google, the problem may actually be that you're missing the Python module txAMQP. You can install the module with:

```
pip install txamqp
```

or on Ubuntu (tested on Ubuntu 14.04)

```
sudo apt-get install python-txamqp
```